# can someone explain me this logic in redux-form validation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, syntax, redux-form

I already know what is the result of this, but I can't understand what type of logic is, is this a if or something similar?

```
 {touched &&
    ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
      (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
```

from

```
<div>
<label>{label}</label>
<div>
  <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
  {touched &&
    ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
      (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, `&&` operator stops on first false value and returns that value. but `||` keeps looking until it founds a truthy value.

e.g.

```
true && 1 && 0; // 0
true && 1 && 'Hello'; // 'Hello'
false && true; // false

true || false || 1; // true
false || 'something'; // 'something'
```

So in this case you are showing error or warning only if field is `touched` so it will move onward only if `touched` is `true`.

When `touched` will be `true` then it will look for `error` and if it is `false`, `||` operator will return next value which is warning.

Answer (score 0):

Those are stating "display an error and/or warning span, if and only if the error/warning is defined". The idea is that the span is not created if warning/error are null/undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First, if `touched` is false, the rest of the expression is ignored and nothing is rendred.

If `error` evaluated to `true`, then `error && <span>{error}</span>` is truthy (since React element is truthy too), and `<span>{error}</span>` is rendered. In this case the second `warning && <...>` does not get evaluated.

If `error` is falsy, then the `warning && <span>{warning}</span>` is evaluated, and if `warning` is truthy the `<span>{warning}</span>` gets rendered.

What the doc says on this: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator:

> true && expression always evaluates to expression, and false &&
>   expression always evaluates to false.
>
> Therefore, if the condition is true, the element right after && will
>   appear in the output. If it is false, React will ignore and skip it.

You can achieve the same outside of jsx expression:

```
let element;
if (touched) {
 if (error) element = <span>{error}</span>;
 else if (warning) element = <span>{warning}</span>;
}

return (
  <div>
    <input {...input} placeholder={label} type={type} />
    {element}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s similar to:

```
if (touched) {
  if (error) {
    // error
  } else if (warning) {
    // warning
  }
}
```

It’s showing error / warning, if there’s any, when field is touched.

Answer (score 0):

They are `[logical && expression]` syntax used in [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator). 
To put it in a way so you can understand it easier:

```
if (touched) {
  if (error) {
   display(error)
  } else if (warning) {
   display(warning)
  }
}
```